# how to show a 2D map in a game?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make an android game, i'm not new to programming but new to developing games, i made a 2D map in PHP on server side, it has 5 kind of tiles, the whole map has about 100000 tiles, I know I should show it in small parts, every thing works fine but I don't know how should I show it in android side, i'm grateful for any guide...

- what XML layout should I use for this map??
- am I wrong about everything above and i need to make a game map by another way?
- if there is a better way to make a smooth map like google map for a game, I would be very grateful to let me know about that...

I have tried table layout but I have got some lag on that, I want this to work smoothly like google map

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

            TableRow tableRow1 = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tableRow1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor( R.color.colorPrimary));
            tv1.addView(tableRow1);

            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                final ImageButton img = new ImageButton(this);
                img.setPadding(0,1,0,1);
                img.setClickable(true);
                if ( TheTile == 1 )
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.plain);
                }
                if ( TheTile == 2 )
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.woods);
                }
                if ( TheTile == 3 )
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.rocks);
                }
                if ( TheTile == 4 )
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.city);
                }
                if ( TheTile == 5 )
                {
                    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.lake);
                }
                tableRow1.addView(img);
            }
        }
```

I want a solution to make it work smoothly and user can zoom in and zoom out, but have some problem about choosing xml layout

Comment: I used the google maps API a couple of years ago to [create a fantasy map](https://github.com/PPartisan/FantasyMapTutorial) with tile overlays  - it may be of use to you?

Comment: @PPartisan yes, thank you very much... many thanks that's a good one, I will try it!!

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: @MorrisonChang I saw it just now, thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think this can be use for a map in a game... because i need to do lots of actions on the map, this is very useful for images not my map, but thank you anyway